# cannot parse json (body) object in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am very new to `Node.JS`, can anyone help in below issue.

I am calling `REST API` and it is returning response  `body` wiht `JSON object`. But i am not able to parse it properly.

I tried `body.destination_addresses[0]` to retrieve value but doesn't work.

Here is my code sample

```
 var parsedjson=JSON.parse(body);
 body.destination_addresses[0];
```

with parsing I am able to retrieve value of `body.destination_addresses[0]` but failed to retrieve `"parsedjson.rows.elements[1].distance.text"` value.

How can I retrieve distance value from `JSON`.

sample json

```
body:
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "458-500 St Johns Pl, Brooklyn, NY 11238, USA",
      "395 4th Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11215, USA"
      ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "127 Tech Pl, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2.3 mi",
                  "value" : 3624
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 899
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
  ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your elements array has only one item so you can't get at index `1`

As per your sample try this code

`body.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text`

You need to clear your basic JavaScript and how to use array

Comment: hi,thanks for the response. Still no luck i tried body.rows[i].elements[i].distance.text; (here value of i = 0). error msg: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined"" .Do you have any idea. [FYI, in my response i have more than 10 values in elements array thats why mentioned elements[1] in my question].

Comment: That should work in your case, you are doing something wrong cross check your code, you can post your all response to help

Comment: yeah you are corrct its working, i made mistake in increment "i" value and referring that in rows. thanks again..